# MySQL select Random whole number

Tags: mysql, random

I want to create a mysql query where I pick one random number between two values including those values (1 and 5 in my example below) and that random value forms part of my where clause. How can this be done.

My code is below for my attempt at this:

`SELECT * WHERE Col7 = (RAND()*(5-1+1)+1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following, using [`RAND`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) and [`FLOOR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor):

```
SELECT FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 5));
```

So your query looks like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Col7 = FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 5))
```

---

> Returns a random floating-point value `v` in the range `0 <= v < 1.0`. To obtain a random integer `R` in the range `i <= R < j`, use the expression `FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j − i))`. For example, to obtain a random integer in the range the range `7 <= R < 12`, use the following statement: `SELECT FLOOR(7 + (RAND() * 5));`
>
> **source:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

---

You can also create a new [`FUNCTION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) to use these instead of the [`RAND`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RAND_INT (minVal INT, maxVal INT)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
RETURN FLOOR(minVal + (RAND() * (maxVal + 1 - minVal)));
```

You can use the created function `RAND_INT` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Col7 = RAND_INT(1, 5);
```

Comment: No @Cid. `RAND()` returns a positive fraction. So `0<(RAND() * 5)<5` and `1<=FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 5))<=5` as FLOOR will take off the decimal part that could be greater than 5.

Comment: @cdaiga my deleted comment was about his first answer `SELECT * WHERE Col7 = FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 6))`, before he edits it

Answer (score 0):

You might need to round the randomly generated number

If you need a random number between 1 and 5 (including both) your query might be :

```
SELECT * WHERE Col7 = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * (5 + 1 - 1))
```

If you need a random number between 2 and 7 (including both) your query might be :

```
SELECT * WHERE Col7 = FLOOR(2 + RAND() * (7 + 1 - 2))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for diversity of solutions

```
SET @rnd := rand();
SELECT * WHERE Col7 = CASE WHEN @rnd < 0.2 THEN 1 
                           WHEN @rnd < 0.4 THEN 2 
                           WHEN @rnd < 0.6 THEN 3 
                           WHEN @rnd < 0.8 THEN 4 
                           ELSE 5 
                      END
```